# Find endpoint created by a 90° angle

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry

I don't really know if this is possible, but is there a way I can find the point A and B on the image bellow?

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Robn1.png)

So how can I find the coordinates of A and B if I know the coordinates of the point P, and I know that PA should form a 90 degree angle.

Here is also another example, which will maybe help you understand what I want to achieve.

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xg2r.png)

Comment: What did you try? Which programming language are you using? Also, how is your rectangle defined? Is `O` the origin of your vector space? Is it always in the center of the rectangle? Is `P` always inside? ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified problem details again...

OK, let coordinate origin is rectangle center `O`, half-width is `wh`, half-height is `hh`

So we can write line equation in [normal form](https://schooltutoring.com/help/equation-of-a-line-normal-form/#:%7E:text=x%20Cos%20%C3%B8%20+%20y%20Sin,from%20the%20origin%20is%20p.)

```
x * px/ro + y * py/ro - ro = 0
 or
x * px + y * py - squared_ro = 0
 where
ro = sqrt(px*px + py*py)
```

Now we can substitute rectangle side coordinates into this equation and find intersections

```
wh * px + y * py - squared_ro = 0  //to get y-coordinate of intersection with right side 
-wh * px + y * py - squared_ro = 0 //y for left side   
x * px + hh * py - squared_ro = 0  //x for top side 
x * px - hh * py - squared_ro = 0   //x for bottom side
```

filter out results where `abs(x)> wh` or `abs(y) > hh` and you'll get two  intersection points